# Differentiating problem under integral sign

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

I have the following integral

$$V\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\left(t\right)\left(z\left(t\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}{a+\left(z\left(t\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}dt$$

where $x$ , $z$ are variables that depends on time and $a$ is an arbitrary constant.

I try to find $\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}$. I tried to use Leibniz rule but I am not sure if it is really the rule to use for this problem since Leibniz rule is used mostly in partial derivatives for constant terms if I am right. 
Thanks for any help or hints !

Comment: But you are integrating with respect to the variable $t$. The result should be in terms of either $\alpha$ or $a$.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai yes, but my aim is to differentiate it rather than finding a solving the integral

Comment: How to differentiate with respect to the variable of integration ?

Comment: An example could be in this paper (in economics)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ps9b5vptrhbwbya/Ricci%20-%202007%20-%20Environmental%20policy%20and%20growth%20when%20inputs%20are%20differentiated%20in%20pollution%20intensity.pdf?dl=0

the author differentiated as I try to do it on equation (23) page 301.

Comment: It seems that he doesn't. He takes the partial derivative of a free variable.